# Lista não carrega dados do banco com xamarin.forms e c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Criei uma lista por código e não consigo carregar os dados. Fiz essa lista pelo `xaml` e também não e tenho outra que funciona(`xaml`) e tentei fazer da mesma forma e nada. Quando subo a lista aparece:

```
Autorizador.Model.ItensLib
```

Abaixo o código

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPageItens : ContentPage
    {
        List<ItensLib> _data { get; set; }
        int _idorcamento = 0;
        List<ItensLib> itens;
        DataService dataService = new DataService();

        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        public MainPageItens()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MainPageItens(int idorcamento)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IdOrcamento = idorcamento;
            Task.Run(async () => await CarregaDados(IdOrcamento)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            ListView lv = new ListView() { HasUnevenRows = true, SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None };
            lv.ItemsSource = _data;

            this.Content = lv;
        }

        async Task CarregaDados(int idorcamento)
        {
            try
            {
                _data = await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(idorcamento);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string erro = ex.Message;
            }

        }

        private void listaItens_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var libera = e.SelectedItem as Liberacao;
                _idorcamento = libera.IdOrcamento;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private async void btnVoltar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
        }

        private async void btnOk_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Com xaml eu faço assim:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout>
                <Editor x:Name="edtMotivo" HeightRequest="40" InputTransparent="False">

                </Editor>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnOK" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="OK" 
                    Clicked="btnOk_Clicked" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="" />
                <Button x:Name="btnVoltar" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Cancelar" 
                    Clicked="btnVoltar_Clicked" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="editar.png" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="listaItens"  ItemSelected="listaItens_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ViewCell>
                            <!--<ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>-->

                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Produto}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="270"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Qtde}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="320"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding UltCondicao}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="520"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Unitario}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="240"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Total}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="240"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**EDIT1**
Consegui trazer os dados, mas o texto ficou na vertical. Fiz por xaml. Veja o screenshot de meu dispositivo e depois o meu xaml?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E meu xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Autorizador.MainPageItens">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="listaItens"  ItemSelected="listaItens_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <!--<ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                        <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>-->

                                <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Produto}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="270"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Qtde}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="320"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding UltCondicao}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="520"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Unitario}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="240"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Total}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="240"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
           </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Editor x:Name="edtMotivo" HeightRequest="40" InputTransparent="False">

                </Editor>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnOK" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="OK" 
                    Clicked="btnOk_Clicked" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="" />
                <Button x:Name="btnVoltar" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Cancelar" 
                    Clicked="btnVoltar_Clicked" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Image="editar.png" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou depois que eu removi o padding do stacklayout, esse padding:

```
<StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
```

Troquei do xaml para o code behind e fiz assim e funcionou:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            //Task.Run(async () => await CarregaDados(IdOrcamento)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            await CarregaDados(IdOrcamento); 

            ListView lv = new ListView() { HasUnevenRows = true, SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.Default, BackgroundColor=Color.White,SeparatorColor=Color.Gold };
            lv.ItemsSource = _data;

            lv.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
            lv.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Produto");
            lv.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "Unitario");

            this.Content = lv;

            //listaItens.ItemsSource = _data;
        }
```